# Sample names without duplicates, without introducing bias

Tags: sampling, bias

I have a set of people objects, each with a unique ID and possibly non-unique name. I'd like to sample some number of them and ensure the sample does not have duplicate names. My issue is that the naive method, of resampling any duplicated names, results in people with non-unique names having a lower probability of being sampled. Is there a way to do this without introducing bias?

Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that this isn't possible, but happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* method you use if you want to ensure non-duplicated names will result in people with less common names having a higher probability of being sampled.

As a thought experiment, suppose you want to sample $k$ objects out of $n$, but there are only $k<n$ names, so each name has to be sampled exactly once. Of these, $k-1$ names occur $m\geq 2$ times each, and the $k$-th name occurs only once. (So $n=m(k-1)+1$.) Then each object with a duplicated name has a chance of $\frac{1}{m}$ of being sampled (because it is a member of a group of size $m$, one of which *must* be sampled, because we have to choose one member from each "name group"), and the single object with a non-duplicated name will be chosen with certainty, i.e., with probability $1$.

Comment: If the sample to be drawn is smaller than the population, will weighted sampling without replacement give the desired sample?

Comment: No, perhaps I am missing the point. Suppose the population is $x = (1,2,3,3,4,5,6)$ and we want a sample of size 3. Then we could do `> sample(unique(x), 3, prob=table(x)/length(x), rep=FALSE)`  or not?

Comment: @utobi: Ah, no, the misunderstanding is mine, sorry, I'm confused today, I'll delete my comment. No, but your example does not address the OP's question. They want to sample *from the 7 individuals*, not from the 6 names, but with the condition that each "name" only occurs once.  Then the two individuals with name $3$ will always have a lower probability each of being chosen than the five individuals with unique names. (Unless we remove one of the individuals named $3$. Then everybody who is left will have the same probability. But the removed one has probability $0$.)

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thanks for the clarification.